# In $(\mathbb{R}^4,\omega_{std})$ is positive symplectic area enough to guarantee a pseudoholomorphic disc representative?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, lagrangian-submanifolds, pseudo-holomorphic-curves

I will present my question in the context that I encountered it, although I believe it probably applies in general context.
Consider $\mathbb{R}^4 \cong \mathbb{C}^2$ with the standard symplectic form $\omega = \sum dp_k\wedge dq_k$. Consider a Lagrangian $L\cong S^1 \times S^1$ given by the product of two circles, $A$ and $B$, each lying in an $\mathbb{R}^2$ factor of $\mathbb{R}^4$.
Consider a class $\alpha\in\pi_2(\mathbb{R}^4,L)$, such that $\omega(\alpha)>0$.

1) Does there exists an almost complex structure $J$ compatible with  $\omega_{std}$ such that $\alpha$ is represented by a $J$-holomorphic disc $u$ with boundary mapped to $L$?

Note that for the integrable complex structure $J_{std}$ that comes from $\mathbb C$ this is true only for $\alpha$ of the form $kA+mB$, where $k,m\ge0$ (here I abused notation and referred to the discs bounded by the circles $A$ and $B$ using the same letters)

2) If the answer to 1 is positive, can $J$ be chosen to be regular? (in the sense that all the moduli spaces of curves are being cut out transversally).

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes. The boundary of a holomorphic disc on $S^1 \times S^1$ is subcritical isotropic, and we can use Gromov's h-principle to move its boundary (by a Hamiltonian isotopy) to the sought curve on $a S^1 \times b S^1$, given that the latter curve bounds the same symplectic area. (I.e. we must first rescale the initial disc appropriately.) The new disc has boundary on $a S^1 \times b S^1$ and is pseudoholomorphic for the push-forward of the standard complex structure under the Hamiltonian diffeomorphism (this complex structure is also compatible with $\omega_0$!).

1b) Since there is an h-principle also for open Lagrangian submanifolds, under the additional condition that Maslov index of the two curves on the respective tori coincide, one can arrange so that even an *open neighbourhood* of the initial Lagrangian $S^1 \times S^1$ is mapped into target Lagrangian $aS^1 \times bS^1$ by the Hamiltonian diffeomorphism.

2) In some explicit cases it is obviously not possible to achieve regularity. For instance, the symplectic embedding $z \mapsto (a \overline{z},bz)$ from the unit disc to a disc of Maslov index zero with boundary on $aS^1 \times bS^1$, $b>a>0$, can be made pseudoholomorphic, but is never regular.

The refined construction in (1b) does however produce regular discs, given that the initial disc was regular.

Comment: 1) Maybe I am missing something, but to use the h-principle here, shouldn't the curve on $S^1\times S^1$ and the sought curve on $aS^1 \times b S^1$ be of the same class in H^1?

i.e let's say I want to get a curve of class (1,-1) on $aS^1 \times b S^1$ (for a > b, so area is still positive).  Then I start with something of class $(1,-1) \in H^1(S^1 \times S^1)$, but this class bounds no holomorphic discs. (zero area)

Comment: The h-principle that I refer to is for curves inside $\mathbb{R}^4$, for which there obviously is no homotopy obstruction. The disc constructed would in the end intersect the torus in a very chaotic way, but at least the boundary will be controlled (and on the torus inside the right class). This is all we need.